# RadComboBoxItem set_text gives SyntaxError: illegal character

Tags: asp.net, ajax, telerik, radcombobox

I'm using Telerik UI for ASP.NET AJAX and I'm trying to populate a `RadComboBox` but I'm getting this error and I don't know why.

My `RadComboBox`:

```
<telerik:RadComboBox ID="regTypeComboBox" runat="server" Width="305" Skin="Telerik" OnClientLoad="OnClientLoadHandler" />
```

My js:

```
function OnClientLoadHandler(sender) {
    var combo;
    combo = sender;

    var serviceUrl = "myUrl";

    var paramData = {

    };

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: serviceUrl,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        crossDomain: true,
        data: JSON.stringify(paramData),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {
            var listData = response.listData;
            $.each(listData, function (index, element) {
                var name, id;
                name = element.NAME;
                id = element.ID;
                var comboItem = new Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBoxItem();
                comboItem.set_text(name); // --> SyntaxError: illegal character

                //comboItem.set_text("name"); // --> also SyntaxError: illegal character

                //comboItem.set_text(""); // --> also SyntaxError: illegal character
                //comboItem.set_text(); // --> also SyntaxError: illegal character
                //comboItem.set_text(1); // --> also SyntaxError: illegal character
                combo.trackChanges();
                combo.get_items().add(comboItem);
                combo.commitChanges();
            });

},
        error: function () {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
}
```

It is pretty simple, but I don't know why it gives this error.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: You're right, this is fairly straight-forward stuff and your syntax all looks fine.  Have you looked into issues with Telerik itself?  Maybe a version mismatch or something like that?  I'm wondering if it doesn't recognize the .set_text function itself, since that is a Telerik-specific thing.

Comment: Try adding the item to the combo fist, then set its text? Just a wild guess as this seems OK to me. Have you tried opening a case with Telerik?

Comment: Thanks, but I gave up. Telerik UI for ASP.NET AJAX is not good for me.